# Verify Gnosis Safe tx: How can I generate the safeTxHash without “Read as Proxy”?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am using the process described in this guide [How to verify Gnosis Safe transactions on a hardware wallet](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4818770-how-to-verify-gnosis-safe-transactions-on-a-hardware-wallet) in order to verify what I am signing on my hardware wallet.

However, I like to generate the safeTxHash without having to use the “Read as Proxy” function on Etherscan. I have been in situations where I could not rely on Etherscan to provide me this functionality so I’m looking for an alternative.

Is there an alternative way to execute the `getTransactionHash` function on my Safe contract, without using the “Read as Proxy” on Etherscan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction hash is generated based on [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) and you can use this logic to calculate the hash off-chain.

An example for this can be found in the Safe contracts repository: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/src/utils/execution.ts#L64-L66

Comment: Thanks this helped! Quickly whipped it up on a web ui to make it easy for me and my team to use. Sharing it here in case someone might find it useful:  [getSafeTxHash](https://s01e01.github.io/Playground/ethereum/getSafeTxHash/index.html)